# Angular JS Service / Factory data is not working with then function

Tags: angularjs, service, q, angular-promise

I'm writing an login form which calls userAuth service and checks the credentials.

When I use, then in my usercontroller I dont get the response or the functions is not even executed.

**userController.js**

```
'use strict'; 

myApp.controller('userController',['sessionFactory','$scope', '$http','$rootScope','$state', '$stateParams','userAuth', function 
                                                            (sessionFactory,$scope,$http,$rootScope,$state, $stateParams,userAuth) {
$scope.user={email:'learner@gmail.com',password:'123456'}

$scope.sigin = function(credentials){

    console.log(userAuth.login(credentials)); //For Testing purpose only
    userAuth.login(credentials).then(function(response){
        console.log("I am inside then function");           //Not Executed
        console.log(response);                              // Not Executed
        });
console.log("I am out of then function");                   // Executed
$scope.loading = false;                                     // Executed

};


}]);
```

**userAuth.js**
    myApp.service('userAuth', function($http,$rootScope,$q){

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

this.login = function(credentials){
    credentials['action']='login';
    $http.post($rootScope.baseURL+'assets/api/user.php',credentials)
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){

        deferred.resolve = "success";
        console.log(data);            //For test purpose only. Its returning data

    })
    .error(function(data,status,headers,config){

        deferred.reject = "failed";


    });

    return deferred.promise;


}



});
```

What am I missing out?[image: Console.log output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deferred.resolve and deferred.reject are functions and not variables, so try:

```
deferred.resolve("success");
deferred.reject("failed");
```

Comment: Thank you for noting the mistake.

Comment: I got an query. Is it necessary that i need to call a service for backend operations. Cant i run in controller itself. Which is preferred.